# How to embed this Processing sketch on Tumblr?

Tags: tumblr

I have a [Processing sketch](http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/155646) that I'd like to embed on my Tumblr. I've followed the instructions on [this post](http://opensourceart.tumblr.com/post/17533740730/how-to-embed-processing-js-sketches-into-tumblr) for doing so, but all I get is an empty canvas and my script showing up as text.

I definitely have the required code they mention in my blog's header tags and have enabled plaintext/HTML as my text-editor. My code matches their format and I stripped all the returns out of the Processing sketch - is there some Tumblr-magic I've neglected, or is there an easier way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same problem! What worked for me was to put a div at the beginning (before canvas...) and a /div at the end (after /script) when you are in the html editor.

[image: CODE]

[image: RESULT]

Or maybe you could try with this "tumbleryfier" found at http://p5lyon.tumblr.com/ProcessingJSTumblrEn